# Cask seems to be ignoring depends upon

Tags: cask

My package depends upon **org 9**. I want to use cask to enforce this dependency.

The way to specify this in my cask file would seem to be `(depends-on "org" "9.0.1")` as documented
[here](https://cask.github.io/dsl.html#depends-on).

However cask seems to be ignoring the version specified.
The following is some sample output demonstrating this.

```
> cat Cask && cask install && cask update && cask eval "(progn (require 'org) (message (org-version)))" && cask --version && emacs -q --eval "(progn (require 'org) (message (org-version)))" --batch
(source gnu)
(source melpa)

(package "org-db-link" "0.1.0" "Quickly navigate and search your emacs org trees")
(files "org-db-link.el")

(depends-on "org" "9.0.1")
8.2.10
0.8.1
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...

Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50ecasound-el.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50festival.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50pylint.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50python-docutils.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50texlive-lang-english.el (source)...
```

### 8.2.10

```

I have tried running `cask upgrade` but this did not help.